# flash external preloader to load a swf thats loading another file

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have my preloader loading my main swf where I'm loading another swf that contains a background.

When my preloader is done it shows my main swf but it takes a while after that for the background to load.

Whats the easiest way to get my preloader to wait until the background swf is done loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main swf must somehow communicate this fact to the preloader - there's no way for the preloader to find out for itself. Considering having the main swf fire an event that the preloader is listening for, or just use a callback function.